# Calling another function from completion handler

Tags: swift, handler, completionhandler, completion

I need to call a second function from within a completion handler, sending the data returned from the first function, stored in the completion handler to the second function, however I get the following error within the completion handler when trying to send returnStatus to second function:

*'CKApplicationPermissionStatus' is not convertible to 'TestLoginViewController'*

**First Function**

```
func checkPermissoins(returnHandler: @escaping (CKApplicationPermissionStatus) -> ()){
    var container = CKContainer.default()
    var currentuserID : CKRecordID?
    var publicDatabase: CKDatabase?
    var returnStatus: CKApplicationPermissionStatus?

    CKContainer.default().requestApplicationPermission(.userDiscoverability) { (status, error) in
        print(status)

        returnHandler(status)
    }

}
```

**Completion Handler**

```
let checkPermissoinsHandler: (CKApplicationPermissionStatus) -> () = {(returnStatus) in

    performCheck(returnStatus)

}
```

**Second Function**

```
func performCheck(returnedStatus: CKApplicationPermissionStatus){ }
```

Comment: Which line exactly is failing? Is it `returnHandler(status)` in your "First Function"? What does the `print` statement before it show you?

Comment: no the line that is failing is performCheck(returnStatus)

Comment: It should be `performCheck(returnedStatus: returnStatus)`

Comment: I have change it and now get the following error: Instance member 'performCheck' cannot be used on type 'TestLoginViewController'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Comment: Then there's something we're not seeing in your code, because we don't see that class being used.